# Express small, large veblen ordinal using ...... (repeat symbol) form

Tags: logic, set-theory, ordinals

Sometimes it's better to see once than to say a thousand words.
Following link shows what ordinals really looks like :

[Ordinal tetration: The issue of ${}^{\epsilon_0}\omega$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2313576/ordinal-tetration-the-issue-of-epsilon-0-omega)

And following is a screenshot of above link.

[image]

So the answerer couldn't(or didn't) show small veblen or large veblen ordinal in similar form.

Q1) Can you express small or large veblen ordinal in this form ?

Q2) Is it possible to define mathematically rigorously following statement? Then how far can we express in such form ?

+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
**An ordianl `O` can be expressed using**

integers
$\omega$
...... (the repeating symbol)
addition
multiplication
exponentiation
up-arrow symbol
other symbols?(maybe some steps further than up-arrow symbol?)
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

Q3) Can you express bachmann-howard ordinal in this form, not using any big (bigger than $\omega$) ordinals ?

Comment: upvoted this one

Comment: Patterns can be extended in more than one way, so what would be the meaning of some expression such as "$\omega\uparrow^2(\omega\uparrow^1\uparrow(\omega\uparrow^{17}\ldots))$"?